# Is it possible to put element inside input field?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is possible insert element inside input fields? Here is an example:

[image: example]

What I can use to make that happen?

I was wondering about tables, It is possible make a table inside input field?

```css
.box-login {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.box-login .bots {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radx-inpuius: 3px;
  -ms-border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative
}

.box-login .box-inputs .line-input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 0;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 0px;
  border-top: 0px;
  border-right: 0px;
}

.box-login .btn-login {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  -ms-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  background-color: #009edb;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<form class="box-login">

  <div class="box-inputs">
    <label class="box-input" for="cpf"></label>
    <input class="line-input" id="cpf" type="text" placeholder="CPF">
  </div>

  <div class="box-inputs">
    <label for="box-input">
            <input class="line-input" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Senha">
            </label>

  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn-login">ENTRAR</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Use a pseudo element or it looks like your inputs are already wrapped you can use <i>

Comment: Thank you @Darkrum that maybe help! Do you can send me a example?

Comment: @epascarello Like that image: https://prnt.sc/j7nki6 , I was taking a look for ::before (CSS pseudo element). For a test i've added that at CSS: line-input::before {
content: url("loading.gif");
 } but nothing happened

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to do this could be having an element with postion: absolute and place it above the input field. Try this code.

```
<form class="box-login"  >

        <div class="box-inputs">
            <span class="icon"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wpzoom-developer-icon-set/500/102-128.png"></span>
            <label class="box-input" for="cpf"></label>
            <input class="line-input" id="cpf" type="text" placeholder="CPF">
        </div>

        <div class="box-inputs">
            <span class="icon"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wpzoom-developer-icon-set/500/102-128.png"></span>
            <label for="box-input">
            <input class="line-input" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Senha">
            </label>

        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="btn-login">ENTRAR</button>
</div>
</form>

.box-login{width:300px;height:auto;margin:0 auto}
 .box-login .bots{width:100%;height:auto;margin:0;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;-moz-border-radx-inpuius:3px;-ms-border-radius:3px;box-shadow:0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);box-shadow:0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);-moz-box-shadow:0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);-ms-box-shadow:0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);background-color:#fff;position:relative}

 .box-login .box-inputs .line-input{width:100%;height:50px;padding-left:40px;position:relative;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;
border-left:0px;
border-top: 0px;
border-right:0px;
 }

 .box-login .btn-login{width:100%;margin:0;height:50px;color:#fff;border-radius:0 0 3px 3px;-webkit-border-radius:0 0 3px 3px;-moz-border-radius:0 0 3px 3px;-ms-border-radius:0 0 3px 3px;background-color:#009edb;


    border: none;}

  .box-inputs {
    position: relative;
  }
  .box-inputs .icon {
    position: absolute;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .box-inputs .icon img {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Comment: A little at a time and I'm getting better, thank you for sharing your knowledge

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot have **any** element contained within an **[`<input>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)**.
It is an **[empty (void) element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/empty_element)**, and the closing tag must be ommitted.
Thus you cannot have any element contained within it.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Do you have any idea how to make it work? I mean, if the input comes just a little bit away to fit a table? or maybe make a div with padding?

Comment: You can make use of `margin` and `padding` to control the alignment / offset of elements. But you certainly cannot contain any other element within an `<input>` element.

Comment: Is there a practical way to build a table just to delimit the use of an icon before the input starts? in case with border 0 if yes, could you help me on this? the pseudo element as suggested did not work