# Hide/show toggle inside password input

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I was wondering how I could place a svg toggle button inside the `input['password']` like this

[image: show password]

and when this is clicked, it would be displayed as this:

[image: hide password]

I've made a simple version, with a checkbox, but I don't know how to do this with a svg, and make it toggle.

The svg images I use is posted in the code.

```js
function togglePass() {
  var x = document.getElementById("login-form-password");
  if (x.type === "password") {
    x.type = "text";
  } else {
    x.type = "password";
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="signin_title">Sign in</p>
<input type="text" id="login-form-username" name="os_username"  placeholder="Username" required><br><br>
<!-- Password -->
<input type="password" id="login-form-password" name="os_password" placeholder="Password" required><br>

<!-- An element to toggle between password visibility -->
<input type="checkbox" onclick="togglePass()">Show Password

<br><p>When password is hidden</p>
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" width="25" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><title>eye-glyph</title><path d="M320,256a64,64,0,1,1-64-64A64.07,64.07,0,0,1,320,256Zm189.81,9.42C460.86,364.89,363.6,426.67,256,426.67S51.14,364.89,2.19,265.42a21.33,21.33,0,0,1,0-18.83C51.14,147.11,148.4,85.33,256,85.33s204.86,61.78,253.81,161.25A21.33,21.33,0,0,1,509.81,265.42ZM362.67,256A106.67,106.67,0,1,0,256,362.67,106.79,106.79,0,0,0,362.67,256Z"/></svg><br>
<p>When password is shown </p>
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" width="25" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><title>eye-disabled-glyph</title><path d="M409.84,132.33l95.91-95.91A21.33,21.33,0,1,0,475.58,6.25L6.25,475.58a21.33,21.33,0,1,0,30.17,30.17L140.77,401.4A275.84,275.84,0,0,0,256,426.67c107.6,0,204.85-61.78,253.81-161.25a21.33,21.33,0,0,0,0-18.83A291,291,0,0,0,409.84,132.33ZM256,362.67a105.78,105.78,0,0,1-58.7-17.8l31.21-31.21A63.29,63.29,0,0,0,256,320a64.07,64.07,0,0,0,64-64,63.28,63.28,0,0,0-6.34-27.49l31.21-31.21A106.45,106.45,0,0,1,256,362.67ZM2.19,265.42a21.33,21.33,0,0,1,0-18.83C51.15,147.11,148.4,85.33,256,85.33a277,277,0,0,1,70.4,9.22l-55.88,55.88A105.9,105.9,0,0,0,150.44,270.52L67.88,353.08A295.2,295.2,0,0,1,2.19,265.42Z"/></svg>
```

So how exactly do I create this using svg?

Thought about maybe if its possible to use the checkbox, and with some js look if its clicked or not, and change the svg depending on that? and then with some css, try to move it inside the input['password']?
`
Something like this but with a svg

```css
input[type="text"] {
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    padding-right: 50px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    margin-left: -50px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 50px;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text"><input type="submit" value="SVG">
```

Comment: You cannot put an SVG (or any HTML) inside an input element. --- _"No, you cannot have any element contained within an <input> element.
It is an empty (void) element, and the closing tag must be ommitted.
Thus you cannot have any element contained within it."_ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49933903/is-it-possible-to-put-element-inside-input-field

Comment: Use it as an element placed next to the input, just style it to be on top of an input opticaly.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Okay maybe not literally inside, but with some css make it look like its inside, like in the last example I've just posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all, make sure an `id` is only used once! (Second svg changed)
2. You can hide and show the desired `<svg>` `onclick`
3. Wrap the input and svg's into a container for styling
4. I've moved the `onclick` to the `<svg>`

```js
var x = document.getElementById("login-form-password");   // Input
var s = document.getElementById("Layer_1");               // Show pass
var h = document.getElementById("Layer_2");               // Hide pass

function togglePass() {
    if (x.type === "password") {
        x.type = 'text';
        s.style.display = 'none';
        h.style.display = 'inline';
    } else {
        x.type = 'password';
        s.style.display = 'inline';
        h.style.display = 'none';
    }   
}
```

```css
#inputcontainer {
    display: flex;
}
#inputcontainer > svg {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p class="signin_title">Sign in</p>
<input type="text" id="login-form-username" name="os_username"  placeholder="Username" required><br><br>

<div id='inputcontainer'>
  <input type="password" id="login-form-password" name="os_password" placeholder="Password" required></input>

  <svg id="Layer_1" onclick="togglePass()" data-name="Layer 1" width="25" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><title>eye-glyph</title><path d="M320,256a64,64,0,1,1-64-64A64.07,64.07,0,0,1,320,256Zm189.81,9.42C460.86,364.89,363.6,426.67,256,426.67S51.14,364.89,2.19,265.42a21.33,21.33,0,0,1,0-18.83C51.14,147.11,148.4,85.33,256,85.33s204.86,61.78,253.81,161.25A21.33,21.33,0,0,1,509.81,265.42ZM362.67,256A106.67,106.67,0,1,0,256,362.67,106.79,106.79,0,0,0,362.67,256Z"/></svg>
  <svg id="Layer_2" onclick="togglePass()" data-name="Layer 2" width="25" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style='display: none' viewBox="0 0 512 512"><title>eye-disabled-glyph</title><path d="M409.84,132.33l95.91-95.91A21.33,21.33,0,1,0,475.58,6.25L6.25,475.58a21.33,21.33,0,1,0,30.17,30.17L140.77,401.4A275.84,275.84,0,0,0,256,426.67c107.6,0,204.85-61.78,253.81-161.25a21.33,21.33,0,0,0,0-18.83A291,291,0,0,0,409.84,132.33ZM256,362.67a105.78,105.78,0,0,1-58.7-17.8l31.21-31.21A63.29,63.29,0,0,0,256,320a64.07,64.07,0,0,0,64-64,63.28,63.28,0,0,0-6.34-27.49l31.21-31.21A106.45,106.45,0,0,1,256,362.67ZM2.19,265.42a21.33,21.33,0,0,1,0-18.83C51.15,147.11,148.4,85.33,256,85.33a277,277,0,0,1,70.4,9.22l-55.88,55.88A105.9,105.9,0,0,0,150.44,270.52L67.88,353.08A295.2,295.2,0,0,1,2.19,265.42Z"/></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Awsome! Do you think it's possible to move it inside? I've made another example in my post, where I move a input over another, so it looks like its inside.

Comment: This works perfect, just added a margin-left: -30px; to it and it was inside ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to get svg and input into the same div. And little bit Css magic!

For example,

HTML:

```
<div class="inputCover">
    <input type="password" class="input">
    <svg class="icon"></svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.inputCover{
    position: relative; //so, when do you make parent div position relative, then absolute items inside is not goes outside.
}

.input{
    padding: 5px;
    padding-right: 25px; //you can limit input's inside, so text not goes to under of icon
}

.icon{
   position: absolute; //you can make icon on the input like this.
   top: 50%; //icon will be center of the input from top to bottom.
   right: 10px; //right position.
   transform: translateY(-50%); //this is important to make icon perfectly centered.
}
```

I think this is the right answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to place SVG inside input using absolute position, and then to add onclick event on SVG itself. Something like this:

```js
function togglePass() {
  var x = document.getElementById("login-form-password");
  var l1 = document.getElementById("Layer_1");
  var l2 = document.getElementById("Layer_2");
  if (x.type === "password") {
    x.type = "text";
    l1.setAttribute('hidden', true);
    l2.removeAttribute('hidden');
  } else {
    x.type = "password";
    l1.removeAttribute('hidden');
    l2.setAttribute('hidden', true);
  }
}
```

```css
[hidden] { display: none; }

.form-group {
  position: relative;
  width: 170px;
}
.form-group svg {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 2px;
  width: 16px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<p class="signin_title">Sign in</p>
<input type="text" id="login-form-username" name="os_username"  placeholder="Username" required><br><br>
<!-- Password -->
<div class="form-group">
<input type="password" id="login-form-password" name="os_password" placeholder="Password" required>

<svg onclick="togglePass()" id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" width="25" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><title>eye-glyph</title><path d="M320,256a64,64,0,1,1-64-64A64.07,64.07,0,0,1,320,256Zm189.81,9.42C460.86,364.89,363.6,426.67,256,426.67S51.14,364.89,2.19,265.42a21.33,21.33,0,0,1,0-18.83C51.14,147.11,148.4,85.33,256,85.33s204.86,61.78,253.81,161.25A21.33,21.33,0,0,1,509.81,265.42ZM362.67,256A106.67,106.67,0,1,0,256,362.67,106.79,106.79,0,0,0,362.67,256Z"/></svg>
<svg onclick="togglePass()" hidden id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2" width="25" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><title>eye-disabled-glyph</title><path d="M409.84,132.33l95.91-95.91A21.33,21.33,0,1,0,475.58,6.25L6.25,475.58a21.33,21.33,0,1,0,30.17,30.17L140.77,401.4A275.84,275.84,0,0,0,256,426.67c107.6,0,204.85-61.78,253.81-161.25a21.33,21.33,0,0,0,0-18.83A291,291,0,0,0,409.84,132.33ZM256,362.67a105.78,105.78,0,0,1-58.7-17.8l31.21-31.21A63.29,63.29,0,0,0,256,320a64.07,64.07,0,0,0,64-64,63.28,63.28,0,0,0-6.34-27.49l31.21-31.21A106.45,106.45,0,0,1,256,362.67ZM2.19,265.42a21.33,21.33,0,0,1,0-18.83C51.15,147.11,148.4,85.33,256,85.33a277,277,0,0,1,70.4,9.22l-55.88,55.88A105.9,105.9,0,0,0,150.44,270.52L67.88,353.08A295.2,295.2,0,0,1,2.19,265.42Z"/></svg>
</div>
```