# password input show/hide problem with img tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make show and hide for password input, but I don't know how!
please help me!
so, I have one input and after that, I have an img tag and I put img tag into the input password please help me to show and hide password with the img tag.

my code:

```
<label for="password-input" class="password-container">
    <input class="main-input" id="password-input" type="password" minlength="8" title="Must contain 
     at least 8 or more characters" placeholder="رمز عبور" required>
    <img class="password-show-icon" src="Eye-slash.svg" alt="">
</label>
```

and image:

[image]

Comment: Share the JavaScript code that you tried

Comment: actually i don't know js please give me js code

Comment: I'm sorry.......

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70711865/hide-show-toggle-inside-password-input

Comment: i want to do this with img tag

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('password-show-icon')[0].click(function(){
 let type = document.getElementById("password-input").type;
 if(type == "text"){
  document.getElementById("password-input").type= "password";
 }else{
  document.getElementById("password-input").type= "text";
 }

})

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: added one more suggestion with minimal changes in the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this by adding event directly to img itself.

```
 <img class = "password-show-icon" src = "Eye-slash.svg" alt = "" onClick = "togglePasswordView()">

function togglePasswordView() {
    let type = document.getElementById("password-input").type;
    document.getElementById("password-input").type = (type == "text") ? "password" : "text";
}
```

Comment: and I have little qs how can I do when clicked on an image to change the image?

Comment: include this in the function.
if(document.getElementById("password-input").type == "text"){
  document.getElementsByClassName("password-show-icon")[0].src = "image"
 } else {
  document.getElementsByClassName("password-show-icon")[0].src = "image"
 }

Comment: it has problem can you fix it

Comment: if(document.getElementById("password-input").type == "text"){ document.getElementsByClassName("password-show-icon")[0].src = "Eye-slash.svg" } else { document.getElementsByClassName("password-show-icon")[0].src = "Eye.svg" }

Comment: where you added this logic ?

Comment: to script.js file

Comment: function togglePasswordView() {
  let type = document.getElementById("password-input").type;
  document.getElementById("password-input").type = (type == "text") ? "password" : "text";
  let imgSrc = document.getElementsByClassName("password-show-icon")[0].src;
  document.getElementsByClassName("password-show-icon")[0].src = (imgSrc == "Eye-slash.svg") ? "Eye.svg" : "Eye-slash.svg";
 }

Comment: doesn't work again

Comment: just image change part doesn't work

Comment: you should have proper img src. then only it will show

Comment: function togglePasswordView() {
  let type = document.getElementById("password-input").type;
  document.getElementById("password-input").type = (type == "text") ? "password" : "text";
  let imgSrc = document.getElementsByClassName("password-show-icon")[0].src;
  document.getElementsByClassName("password-show-icon")[0].src = imgSrc.includes("Eye-slash.svg") ? "Eye.svg" : "Eye-slash.svg";
 }

Answer (score 0):

I can see how your problem could be confusing. To accomplish what you are trying to do, I would use the z attribute to stack the elements:

```
<label for="password-input" class="password-container"> 
    <input class="main-input" id="password-input" type="password" 
     minlength="8" title="Must contain at least 8 or more characters" 
     placeholder="رمز عبور" required style="position: absolute;z- 
     index:900;">
     <img id="img1" src="" alt="" style="position: absolute;z- 
     index:1000;">My data</img>
</label>
```

Hope that is helpful to you! :)

Comment: You misunderstood my question

Comment: Sorry, thought you wanted html.

Comment: Well you could try using the z index on ```<img>``` tags

Answer (score 0):

You must use javascript in order to toggle the `type` between "password" and "text".

This isn't a code requesting site, but because it's no work, and because you don't know any javascript, I will do you a favor. Make sure to change the `class` to `id` on the image tag, and paste the javascript code at the bottom of your html file.

I will leave it up to you to style the html elements.

```css
#password-show-icon {
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label for="password-input" class="password-container">
    <input class="main-input" id="password-input" type="password" minlength="8" title="Must contain 
     at least 8 or more characters" placeholder="رمز عبور" required>
    <img id="password-show-icon" src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/show-password-icon-eye-symbol-vector-vision-hide-watch-secret-view-web-design-element-240754407.jpg" alt="">
</label>

<script>
  document.getElementById('password-show-icon').addEventListener('click', () => {
    let passwordInput = document.getElementById('password-input')
    let hiddenPassword = passwordInput.type == 'password';
    let type = 'password';

    if (hiddenPassword) {
      type = 'text';
    }

    passwordInput.type = type;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: doesn't work! why?

Comment: i use this css:             .password-show-icon {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 26px;
    left: 153px;
}

Comment: and i don't know why it doesn't work?!

Comment: Do note that you need to have `id="password-show-icon"` on your image. CSS doesn't have anything to do with javascript.

Comment: Also, you need to add the code _at the bottom of the html file_, not inside a script.js file because otherwise the script won't find the HTML because it  haven't loaded when the script runs.